# How would I make sure this square moves and doesn't extend using openGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have a Pong game that I'm working on. Right now, I'm working on getting the player paddle working. Here's what happens right now. The game starts, and the paddle is situated on the screen. Pressing up on the paddle extends the square upwards. Pressing down does the opposite. What I need is for the square to actually move as an individual object and delete itself each time it moves so that it stays a square the entire time. Instead of the paddle getting bigger, I need it to stay the same shape, but just move. How would I go about doing this in openGL? Here are my two classes.

Startup (main class):

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

import com.evanklein.pong.entitity.Player;

public class Startup {

    // set up display
    public void start() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(600, 400)); // these numbers
                                                                // pending
            Display.setTitle("Evan's Pong!");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glOrtho(0, 600, 400, 0, 1, -1);

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

            // render OpenGL here
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glColor3f(3.0f, 7.2f, 6.7f);
            GL11.glVertex2d(player.width, player.length);
            GL11.glVertex2d(player.width + 100, player.length);
            GL11.glVertex2d(player.width + 100, player.length + 100);
            GL11.glVertex2d(player.width, player.length + 100);
            GL11.glEnd();

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);

            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) {
                player.moveUp();
            } 
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) {
                player.moveDown();
            }
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }

    // Let's start this beyotch up!
    Player player = new Player();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Startup().start();
    }
}
```

Player class:

```
public class Player {

    // size variables
    public int width = 50;
    public int length = 120;

    private int moveSpeed = 10; // mph

    public Player() {

    }

    public void moveUp() {
        length -= moveSpeed;
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        length += moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any other questions or need any other remaining details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glClear()` the framebuffer at the beginning of your `isCloseRequested()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have not run the code but it should get you going

In your main class:

```
...
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity(); 
GL11.glOrtho(0, 600, 400, 0, 1, -1);

GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW); // make active the ModelView matrix
GL11.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);        // setup black as the clear color

while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

  GL11.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the screen using the color above

  GL11.glLoadIdentity();   // reset any transformations in the ModelView matrix

  // move the player square to its current position
  GL11.glTranslatef(player.x, player.y, 0); 

  // render OpenGL here
  ....
```

In your player class:

```
  ...
  // add new fields for player's position 
  // change those values according to the desired initial position
  public int x = 100; 
  public int y = 100;  
  ... 

  // change the position of the square, not its dimensions
  public void moveUp() {
      y -= moveSpeed;
  }

  public void moveDown() {
      y += moveSpeed;
  }
```